# SignalR - self-hosting. Communicate with online website

Tags: c#, signalr

First, sorry about the newbie-question. But I can't find any information about this, so I give it a try here!

I'm going to build a chat-app with signalR, where I have a winForms app, where I can recive messages from clients using signalR-chat on there online-websites.

I'm trying to figure out:

If I build a windowsForms-app and use self-hosting. Can I communicate with online websites that way or does self-hosting just works locally on the same domain (ex. localhost:12345) ?